# Declaring a field of vector in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to declare a member with type of Vector of trait in Rust but it is returning this error:

`error: explicit lifetime bound required`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
struct Lion {
    legs: int,
}

trait Animal {
   fn eat(&self);
}

impl Animal for Lion {
    fn eat(&self) {
        println!("Eat");
    }
}

struct Zoo {
    animals: Vec<Animal>,
}
```

I tried to search around the internet on how to fix this error with no luck. Can anyone give me a shed of light? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`Animal` is a trait, which means it could be implemented by just about *anything*.  As such, you have to tell the compiler how long references contained by *each thing that implements `Animal`* in the `Vec` will be valid.

For example, you might have a `Dodo` that contains short-lived lifetime; you wouldn't want it to go extinct whilst it's in your `Vec`, leading to memory unsafety!

You need to use *either*

```
struct Zoo {
    animals: Vec<Animal + 'static>,
}
```

or

```
struct Zoo<'a> {
    animals: Vec<Animal + 'a>,
}
```

The first states that any reference reachable will be valid for the entire lifetime of the program.  The second states that there is some lifetime `'a` for which all references reachable will be valid.  The problem then, however, is that this code isn't valid *anyway* because...

```
error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Animal+'static`
```

You cannot have a `Vec` of values which are dynamically sized, which includes traits.  You can solve this by either using `Box<Animal + 'xxx>`, or `&'xxx Animal + 'xxx`.  A `Box` will be a lot easier to manage.

> **Edit**: To be accurate, any type which accepts a `Sized?` parameter works here.  This boils down to any form of reference indirection.  `Rc` and `Arc` probably work, too.

FYI, that second form basically just says "a borrowed reference which is valid for all of lifetime `'xxx` (the `&'xxx` part) to a value which implements `Animal`, where any references said value contains are valid for *at least* the lifetime `'xxx` (the `+ 'xxx` part)."

Comment: Thanks. How do I instantiate a Box?

Comment: If only they had declared `dodo` with the proper lifetime!